# After migrating website rederection to old website

Tags: php, wordpress

I just migrated my website and it keeps rederection to another domainname of mine. Before I did this I open de SQL file and replaced the old domain with the new one. And imported it this in a new database. After that I configured the wp-admin. So after done this it should work right? In can access the website through wp-admin and that seems to work, but when I just type in the URL it rederection to another old domain of mine.

Anyone any idea how to fix this?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you missed some records in the database. The best approach is to use a tool like https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

If you download this free tool and upload to your server then it does a batch find-and-replace across every single table in your Wordpress database.

So, for example, replace http://www.example.com with http://sub.example.com

You can do a dry run and it will show you all the replaces that it will make. Once you're happy then click the "live run" button and all the changes are made.

I use this tool all the time when I am moving a site from my local machine to the live server. I also use the exact same approach when migrating a site from http to https

Comment: I think that does do the same when i edit the .sql file and replace website1 to website2 in the editor. Or just use sql to replace it. But it is weird because i can access the example.com/wp-admin but when i go to just example.com it redirects the de old website.  Also the .htaccess seems to be right and checked wp_options in mysql.